# WP_Query not returning any results

Tags: wordpress

I have the following code, (written by someone else), which has stopped returning results. I know there are related posts, and nothing has changed in the taxonomy, or database. When I dumped the query I saw "1 = 1  AND (0 = 1)" in it, which obviously would stop it from outputting anything, but I don't know why that's happening.

```
    global $post; 
        $dept_id = get_post_meta($post->ID,'dept_id',true);
        $post_data = get_post($dept_id, ARRAY_A);
        $slug = $post_data['post_name'];
        // Creating the Tax Query           
        $dep_tax_query = array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'department',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $slug,
                            'operator' => 'IN',
                        )
                    );


        // The Query
        $dep_posts = new WP_Query();
        $dep_posts->query( array( 'post_type' => 'post','order' => 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'date', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'tax_query' => $dep_tax_query) );
```

I'm not sure if this is enough information to go on, so please feel free to ask for more if you think you can help me with this. I have no clue why this stopped working. I do know that it stopped after the last update from 4.0 to 4.1, so I'm thinking something in the core code has changed, and perhaps something somewhere is not written to the correct coding standards. Since I didn't write it, it's rather difficult to locate.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Try changing ' post_name' to 'name'
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600239/wordpress-wp-query-search-criteria-on-post-name

Comment: I just tried that. Still no results.